# Calculating Kernel Density output values based on parameter value in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, kernel-density

I am generating a map where I have sentiment value for geo-tagged data. I want to show a heat map based on the sentiment of location. I am using kernel density to generate this map.

I am having trouble in understanding how does the 'kernel density' function calculates output density values when I am entering the sentiment as the parameter?

What role does the radius and area parameter play in the result?

Is kernel density the right option to generate such a map?

I am using ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.